# What pedals would achieve this guitar tone?

Tags: effects

I get the feeling it's a combination of rolling off the treble and octave pedal but I'm not entirely sure and figure someone else out there would be much more informed than I am on this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

That's an Envelope Follower or Envelope Filter. Probably an Auto-Wah.

These pedals basically make a smoothed-curve signal using the (high-)frequency (or amplitude after a band-pass) of the input signal, and then use that as a control parameter, usually for tone/eq/compression attack etc.

For modern pedal simulator software, a single envelope follower can be assigned to multiple parameters on multiple effects: such as simulating a univibe by adjusting wet/dry Dopler Speaker, auto-wah intensity, and phaser modulation speed all at once based on how loud the input signal is.

See, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_detector